# What is the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A\in M_4(\mathbb{F})$, such that the minimal polynomial is $m_A = (x-3)(x^2+6x+10)$. What is $f_A(x)$ (the characteristic polynomial)?

I'd be glad for help.

By the way, I just proved a previous exercise which I can rely on, but I couldn't make the connection. The exercise:

Let $n_1, n_2, l_1, l_2$ natural numbers such that $n_1$ doesn't divide $n_2$. Let $A\in M_{l_1n_1 + (l_2+1)n_2)}(\mathbb{F})$ and $m_A = q_1^{l_1}q_2^{l_2}$ where $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ are irreducible and $\text{deg}(q_1) = n_1$, $\text{deg}(q_2) = n_2$ then $f_A = q_1^{l_1}q_2^{l_2+1}$.

**EDIT**
I've just noticed that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $x^{2}+6x+10$ is irreducible, then since the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial and have the same roots (eigenvalues of the matrix) then the characteristic is $(x-3)^{2}(x^2+6x+10)$

Comment: Then why not $(x-3)(x^2+6x+10)^2$?

Comment: The degree of the characteristic polynomial must be 4.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the degree of a characteristic polynomial is equal to the dimension of the matrix.

Second hint: minimal polynomial is a divisor of the characteristic polynomial.